developing a webhook receiver, it needs to handle time-consuming operations while ensuring a quick response. Any tips on how to achieve both?
As a webhook receiver, I'm tasked with handling time-consuming operations while also ensuring a prompt response to the webhook. What are some effective strategies to achieve both efficiently? Any insights or recommendations are appreciated. Stack is Nodejs Express.
I want to do while chaining middleware like
webHookRouter.post('/customer', saveRawToSQL, filterCustomerData, transferData); 
